# Why don't the fingers from the metarig rotate properly?

Tags: rigging

I searched for the answer but couldn't find it.
I added a metarig to the scene for my character. The complex one with a face and fingers. I've posed the rest of the skeleton in place, however the ringers are giving me grief, as in they will not rotate with the wrist/hand bone otherwise they break apart like so:

[image]

And I can't figure out how to resolve it. Does anyone have any ideas? Would adjusting my fingers in pose mode work? They rotate fine there, but I don't know if somehow doing it in pose mode will cause problems later on.

Comment: what do you mean when you say that they rotate well in Pose mode? Actually you are not supposed to animate in Edit mode but in Pose mode, but maybe share your file

Comment: When I say the fingers rotated well, I mean that when I selected the hand and fingers like in the above image, they rotated without breaking and disconnecting like you would expect. I wasn't animating at this point, I had only just added the metarig to the scene and was posing the skeleton to fit inside of my character so that it would apply auto-weights as correctly as possible. I was following a guide where the person was doing this in edit-mode so I presumed that was the "correct" mode to do so in. But I presume this can be done in pose mode as well? I can still share the file if needed.